# Nested objects of same type ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to model the scenario below.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
Type2 = DS.Model.extend({
    value1: DS.attr('boolean'),
    value2: DS.attr('boolean'),
    value3: DS.attr('boolean')
});
Type1 = DS.Model.extend({
    field1: DS.belongsTo('Type2'),
    field2: DS.belongsTo('Type2')
});
```

1. In the model above it seems like the the parent -`Type1` - does not get updated when I change a field in any of child - `Type2` - objects.
2. What structure will the Json that is returned from the server have to be?
3. The documentation needs to be more descriptive because relationships are very common. Otherwise, the framework is nice. Good job.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try calling save on parent after saving the child.

```
type2.save().then(function(){
  type1.save();
});
```

Comment: I do not think the parent object's `isDirty` ends up returning true after I modify a child. *Edit:* What if I do not want to save? I am constructing UI elements that indicate when fields are dirty.